# Spring Cloud Data Flow Scaling with Apache Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-dataflow

I've followed many Spring tutorials on scaling ([here](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/recipes/scaling/manual-scaling/), and [here](https://spring.io/blog/2021/02/03/demystifying-spring-cloud-stream-producers-with-apache-kafka-partitions)), but still haven't found the secret knock that keeps all consumers busy.  The intent is to have 5 (example) sink processes constantly busy.  The documentation implies that for a simple stream of `source | processor | sink`, I would use the following stream properties:

```
deployer.sink.count=5
app.processor.producer.partitionKeyExpression=headers['X-PartitionKey']?:''
app.sink.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.autoAddPartitions=true
app.sink.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.minPartitionCount=5
```

Naturally, the processor adds a header field called X-PartitionKey that ends up being unique enough that it should balance adequately.

What I find is that only 2 or 3 ever receive messages, and the remainder sit idle.  It feels like the first few watch multiple partitions, and the others just sit in stand-by saying `Found no committed offset for partition`.  I can see by using `kowl` that the messages are getting unique partitions, but the load never gets balanced to reflect as such.

Am I missing configuration somewhere?  Is it a kafka binder issue?

**Update #1**

I've noticed that each instance isn't getting a unique clientId.  Not sure if this is relevant.

```
Instance 1 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-mystream-2, groupId=mystream]
Instance 2 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-mystream-3, groupId=mystream]
Instance 3 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-mystream-3, groupId=mystream]
Instance 4 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-mystream-3, groupId=mystream]
Instance 5 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-mystream-2, groupId=mystream]
```

**Update #2**

Using the below 3 properties, all 5 instances are busy.  This method seems to bypass SCSt and uses a MessageKey instead of PartitionKey.  Not perfect yet, but better.

```
deployer.sink.count=5
app.processor.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.messageKeyExpression=headers['X-PartitionKey']?:''
app.sink.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.autoAddPartitions=true
```

**Update #3**

Adding `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.partition-count` equal to the actual number of Kafka partitions seems to have resolved the issue.  If your `deployer.*.count` property is less than the actual number of partitions, the excess partitions will not be assigned messages, but the consumers will be assigned to them anyways, and may sit idle.

Comment: Show all of the `application.properties`, including the bindings - is there a group are are these anonymous consumers (for the latter, `auto.offset.reset` is set the `latest` by default). Are you sure all partitions are getting data? Also post the startup logs for all instances somewhere like GitHub Gist or PasteBin or similar.

Comment: @GaryRussell I leverage the spring-cloud-dataflow-apps-plugin that the stream-applications project uses as well.  If I filter out the `management`, `sleuth`, and `wavepoint` endpoint properties from the generated `application.properties`, all that's left is ```spring.cloud.config.enabled=false
spring.cloud.function.definition=consumeTransaction
spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.consumeTransaction-in-0=input
```.  Preparing logs, but noticing `clientId` is not being set as unique across the 5 instances `[Consumer clientId=consumer-mystream-2, groupId=mystream]` is repeated.

Comment: OK; with dataflow you will always have a groupId; good. In future, don't put stuff like this in comments, edit the question instead and comment that you have done so. The client-id will be generated by the kafka-clients, unless you specify it yourself so, yes, it will be the same by default.

Comment: Instance [1](https://pastebin.com/raw/xxjdwLU0) [2](https://pastebin.com/raw/1PUVvAne) [3](https://pastebin.com/raw/0T1Zd20U) [4](https://pastebin.com/raw/UmCzTy1T) [5](https://pastebin.com/raw/dJCT017v)

Answer (score 0):

You can clearly see the 10 partitions evenly assigned across the 5 instances, e.g.

```
partitions assigned: [mystream.processor-7, mystream.processor-6]
```

```
1: 3,2
2: 0,1
3: 9,8
4: 5,4
5: 7,6
```

The

```
Found no committed offset for partition mystream.processor-8
```

messages (in all 5 instances) simply means this groupId has never committed an offset for that partition.

These logs are normal for that condition:

> 2022-05-04 17:42:44.067  INFO [sink,,] 1 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-mystream-2, groupId=mystream] Found no committed offset for partition mystream.processor-7

> 2022-05-04 17:42:44.067  INFO [sink,,] 1 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-mystream-2, groupId=mystream] Found no committed offset for partition mystream.processor-6

> 2022-05-04 17:42:44.163  INFO [sink,,] 1 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-mystream-2, groupId=mystream] Resetting offset for partition mystream.processor-7 to position FetchPosition{offset=0, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[dataflow-kafka-0.dataflow-kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], epoch=12}}.

> 2022-05-04 17:42:44.167  INFO [sink,,] 1 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-mystream-2, groupId=mystream] Resetting offset for partition mystream.processor-6 to position FetchPosition{offset=0, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[dataflow-kafka-1.dataflow-kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092 (id: 1 rack: null)], epoch=10}}.

The main consumer is consumer-mystream-2; the repeated logs further down are for `Consumer clientId=consumer-mystream-3` - I think that's the consumer used for the health check - it has the same group but never subscribes to the topic maybe this chatter is because it's in the same group.

The chatter goes away as soon as the main consumer commits the offset of a record.

In any case, if you send a record to each of the 10 partitions, each instance will definitely get 2.

**EDIT**

It works as expected for me, using either native or binder partitioning. The `partitionCount` is automatically adjusted up to match the actual number of partitions and that is used as the modulus when calculating the partition.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So72115288Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So72115288Application.class, args).close();
    }

    List<AtomicInteger> receivedPartitions = new ArrayList<>();

    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(100);

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<String>> input() {
        return msg -> {
            this.receivedPartitions.get(msg.getHeaders()
                    .get(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID, Integer.class))
            .incrementAndGet();
            this.latch.countDown();
        };
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(StreamBridge bridge) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            this.receivedPartitions.add(new AtomicInteger());
        }
        return args -> {
            // native partitioning
//          IntStream.range(0, 100).forEach(i -> bridge.send("output", new GenericMessage<>("foo",
//                  Collections.singletonMap(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, ("key" + i).getBytes()))));
            // binder partitioning
            IntStream.range(0, 100).forEach(i -> bridge.send("output", new GenericMessage<>("foo",
                    Collections.singletonMap("custom", ("key" + i).getBytes()))));
            this.latch.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.println(this.receivedPartitions.stream()
                    .map(ai -> ai.get())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        };
    }

}
```

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-in-0.group=foo
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.partition-count=5
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.partition-key-expression=headers['custom']
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=input-in-0

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.min-partition-count=5
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.auto-add-partitions=true
```

```
[10, 13, 8, 10, 13, 6, 9, 16, 12, 3]
```

Comment: Normally I would agree, but the 10 partitions come from over-partitioning (not sure it can or should be reduced) after a scale out.  There are currently 5 consumers defined in the properties file, so the result of PartitionKey algorithm should be assigning partitions 0-4.  As you noted above, instances 1,2 and 4 might receive data but 3 and 5 would be idle.  I would have hoped each consumer would be assigned at least a unique active partition.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to have 10 partitions but only use 5 of them. You should either distribute the work to all 10 partitions, or use a different `PartitionAssignor` - maybe a custom one. Perhaps the `RoundRobinAssignor` will do what you want.

Comment: Agreed, but I'm working within the parameters of Spring Cloud Dataflow.  It feels like there is a fundamental issue with `Scaling In` after a `Scale Out`.  If I started with 5 partitions, 5 consumers would be ok.  If I `Scale Out` to 10, there would now be 10 partitions, and still ok.  If I `Scale In` to 5, there are still 10 partitions, and the assignment (default to this point) is distributed across 10 (5 of which will never receive data).

Comment: If you use SCSt partitioning by the source, its `partitionCount` must equal the number of partitions, not the number of processor instances (according to the docs here https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_producer_properties it should be adjusted up automatically. Why bother to use partitioning at the SCSt level; that is really intended for brokers that don't have native partitioning. If you just let Kafka's default partitioner do the partitioning (based on the `key` - just set the `MESSAGE_KEY` header to your `X-PartitionKey` value.

Comment: It works as expected for me, with either native or binder partitioning. See the edit.

Comment: Using the combination of `app.processor.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.messageKeyExpression` and `deployer.consumer.count=5` I achieved a pure balance (=great).  I haven't achieved any success on your edits, since the issue isn't assigning a partition, but is in reading from a populated partition (still only 3 of 5 are busy). The messages are being assigned partitions 0-4 which is correct, however I can see some the consumers getting assigned partitions > 4.  I've added a partial update to the original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244522/discussion-between-fiidim-and-gary-russell).